# Excluding a temporary column from MySQL report

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to exclude a column that I'm using as a sort key from displaying in the reporting.  In Oracle I can simply say `COLUMN SORTKEY NOPRINT`, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent in MySQL.  As far as I can tell, I need the sort key so that the rows display in the proper order (Debit, Credit, then Total).

The query I am working with is as follows (it's quite large):

**SQL**

```
SELECT    CASE
        WHEN t.transaction_account = '111-111-111-111' THEN 'Debit'
        WHEN t.transaction_account = '222-222-222-222' THEN 'Credit'
      END AS "Transaction",
      CASE
        WHEN t.transaction_account = '111-111-111-111' THEN 1
        WHEN t.transaction_account = '222-222-222-222' THEN 2
      END AS "SORTKEY",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 1 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Jan",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 2 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Feb",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 3 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Mar",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('1','2','3') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ1",
                LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 4 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Apr",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 5 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "May",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 6 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Jun",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('4','5','6') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ2",
                LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 7 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Jul",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 8 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Aug",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 9 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Sep",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('7','8','9') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ3",
                          LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 10 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount

              ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Oct",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 11 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Nov",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 12 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Dec",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('10','11','12') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ4",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "YTD"
FROM     transaction t INNER JOIN common_lookup cl
ON       t.transaction_type = cl.common_lookup_id
WHERE    cl.common_lookup_table = 'TRANSACTION'
AND      cl.common_lookup_column = 'TRANSACTION_TYPE'
GROUP BY  CASE
       WHEN t.transaction_account = '111-111-111-111' THEN 'Debit'
       WHEN t.transaction_account = '222-222-222-222' THEN 'Credit'
     END
,        CASE
       WHEN t.transaction_account = '111-111-111-111' THEN 1
       WHEN t.transaction_account = '222-222-222-222' THEN 2
     END
UNION ALL
SELECT    'Total' AS "Transaction",
      3 AS "SORTKEY",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 1 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Jan",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 2 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Feb",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 3 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Mar",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('1','2','3') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ1",
                LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 4 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount

              ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Apr",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 5 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "May",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 6 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Jun",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('4','5','6') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ2",
                LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 7 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount

              ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Jul",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 8 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Aug",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 9 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Sep",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('7','8','9') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ3",
                          LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 10 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount

              ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Oct",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 11 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Nov",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) = 12 AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "Dec",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) IN ('10','11','12') AND
                 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                  ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "FQ4",
      LPAD(FORMAT(SUM(
          CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = 2009
            THEN
              CASE
                WHEN cl.common_lookup_type = 'DEBIT'
                  THEN t.transaction_amount
                ELSE t.transaction_amount * -1
              END
          END), 2),10,' ') AS "YTD"
FROM     transaction t INNER JOIN common_lookup cl
ON       t.transaction_type = cl.common_lookup_id
WHERE    cl.common_lookup_table = 'TRANSACTION'
AND      cl.common_lookup_column = 'TRANSACTION_TYPE'
GROUP BY  'Total'
ORDER BY SORTKEY;
```

The query shows as such:

```
+-------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Transaction | SORTKEY | Jan        | Feb        | Mar        | FQ1        | Apr        | May        | Jun        | FQ2        | Jul        | Aug        | Sep        | FQ3        | Oct        | Nov        | Dec        | FQ4        | YTD        |
+-------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Debit       |       1 |   2,957.40 |   4,022.70 |   5,654.04 |  12,634.14 |   4,595.10 |   2,219.64 |   1,300.62 |   8,115.36 |   2,413.62 |   2,149.68 |   2,162.40 |   6,725.70 |   3,291.30 |   3,246.78 |   2,299.14 |   8,837.22 |  36,312.42 |
| Credit      |       2 |    -750.48 |    -992.16 |  -1,437.36 |  -3,180.00 |  -1,217.94 |    -546.96 |    -302.10 |  -2,067.00 |    -597.84 |    -537.42 |    -604.20 |  -1,739.46 |    -829.98 |    -829.98 |    -594.66 |  -2,254.62 |  -9,241.08 |
| Total       |       3 |   2,206.92 |   3,030.54 |   4,216.68 |   9,454.14 |   3,377.16 |   1,672.68 |     998.52 |   6,048.36 |   1,815.78 |   1,612.26 |   1,558.20 |   4,986.24 |   2,461.32 |   2,416.80 |   1,704.48 |   6,582.60 |  27,071.34 |
+-------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any functionality in MySQL that allows this, but I believe you can use `CASE` in `ORDER BY` in MySQL, so you probably don't need to.

```
/* Remove SORTKEY from SELECT */
...
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN t.transaction_account = '111-111-111-111' THEN 1
    WHEN t.transaction_account = '222-222-222-222' THEN 2
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that throws a `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.transaction_account' in 'order clause'` error.

Comment: Assuming it worked in the `SELECT`, it should work in the `ORDER BY`. Make sure you indeed do have such a column and you didn't make a typing error.

Comment: I've double checked the typing and the validity of the column.  No problems there.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: It was simply a problem of aliasing the columns.  Because the column was titled 'Transaction' before the `ORDER BY` had started I simply had to change `t.transaction_account` to `Transaction` and `111-111-111-111` to 'Debit', etc. It then worked fine!